# Favicon changing from page to page in SF

Tags: visualforce, tab, favicon

I've noticed the [favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) in SF seems to be different across random pages in my SF app recently.

It's not a problem as such, I'm just curious why it's only affecting some of my pages and not others.

Does anyone know?

My org is using Summer 15.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have no documentation that confirms this, but from what I have found Production orgs use the White Cloud favicon and Sandbox and Developer Orgs use the Blue cloud favicon.

It actually proves to be a bit handy when you have your production and sandbox open in separate tabs, it's a quick and easy way to tell the difference.

Comment: That makes sense, as I've observed this, too.